# Обновление метрик в прометее

Tags: prometheus

Как из питона заапдейтить метрики. У меня тулза обрабатывает почту и мне нужно количество писем подсчитывать. Поднял прометей в докере. В скрипте делают так:

```
    from prometheus_client import Counter
    def process(self):
            ...
            c = Counter('my_failures_111', 'Description of counter')
            c.inc()  # Increment by 1
```

Как мне `prometheus_client` явно указать, куда класть метрики?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае пром клиент никуда ничего не кладет, а просто создает endpoint по которому заданную метрику пром-сервер может спулить. По дефолту -- /metrics, а в проме надо сделать конфигурацию которая будет ходить на этот endpoint и забирать метрики.

Важно, не забудте сделать `start_http_server(8000)`

Указать прометею, куда ходить можно с помощью [конфига](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#static_config)